# How to block the header x-http-method-override in AWS Cloud front?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, web-application-firewall

In my architecture, it has a cloud front associated with ELB as an origin(https:443)

As a proactive security measure I would like to block the header `x-http-method-override`
can anyone help me how to block the header x-http-method-override  in AWS Cloud front?.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Check [HTTP request headers and CloudFront behavior (custom and Amazon S3 origins)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html).

If you don't configure CloudFront behavior to cache based on header value it does not forward the header to your custom origin.
By default, CloudFront doesn't consider headers when caching your objects in edge locations.

If you are using the Legacy cache settings the option is straightforward, ie. Headers: None.
If you are using Cache policies the option is part of the policy you select and you have the possibility to include or exclude specific headers.